# css code is removed when I tried to pass it through jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am using the following code to submit different values

```
var evalue= 'color:#d32;font-size:12px;';
jQuery.ajax({   
    type: 'get',
    url: 'save.php',
    data: 'type=epush&id=' + qid+'&evalue='+pof+'&efield='+efield,      
    beforeSend: function() {},  
    success: function() {}
});
```

the issue I am having is the value needs to be css code. 
so when I use `$eval= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['evalue']);`
that strips off the code.even when I use `$eval = &_GET['evalue'];` it strips off the # sign.
I used `var evalue` on javascript to make it simple to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the parameters using [`encodeURIComponent(param)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), and then use [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) in PHP.

```
jQuery.ajax({   
    type: 'get',
    url: 'save.php',
    data: 'type=epush&id=' + encodeURIComponent(qid) 
        +'&evalue='+ encodeURIComponent(pof)
        + '&efield='+efield,      
    beforeSend: function() {},  
    success: function() {}
});
```

In PHP:

```
urldecode($_GET['evalue']);
```